# WSO2 API Manager - How to get app token (or keys) when we are an administrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm working with WSO2 am and I'm testing some functionalities.
I' have just one thing I can't find.

How an administrator can find the credentials of an app who was created by an random user.

Maybe an example can help you :
I'm a random user and I create my app, after that, I subscribe to different apis and I get consumer key, secret key and I can generate token.
But the only people who watch this informations, it's me, an administrator can't see this informations.

And what I want it's use those informations (I don't know witch one for the moment) to create in the same time an other account with same credentials in an other platform. The transfer should be made at the hand for the moment but maybe after it will be automatised.

So where can I find those credentials when I am an administrator ? is it possible ?

Thank you very much for you time

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: yes because it's probably in a database and maybe I should create a script or other to get those informations

Comment: Expose credentials to someone else, even admin is not a good practice. No one wants to show their credentials to someone else. Do you share your stackoverflow account credentials with admins of it?

Comment: It's true and I know it's not really a good practice but it's what my team ask me to do so I search a solution. But maybe the solution doesn't exist